# Request MS Access Data via Javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-access, settimeout

I want to connect to a database and retrieve data from a field every 1 second. This loads the first record, but it doesn't request / display any new records. Any ideas?

```
function test() {
  var adOpenForwardOnly = 0,
    adLockReadOnly = 1;
  var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  conn.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data          Source=C:\\path\\Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
  if (conn) {
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rs.Open("SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 where Time1 = time()", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly);
    value1 = rs.fields("Value1").value;
    document.write(value1);
  }
  rs.Close();
  conn.Close();
}
setTimeout(test(), 1000);
```

Comment: how do you plan to use this code? it will only run in IE. and on a client with a valid path to `Data.mdb`. perhaps we could offer a better solution, if we had more information. I wouldn't normally recommend `ActiveX`, `setTimeout`, or `setInterval` for anything...

Comment: Yes, i know, it's really tricky.  I need it to connect to an MS Access database locally to gather the information and refresh it every second.  I know how to do it using PHP, but in this case i'm just using a database locally and a windows PC so PHP is out of the equation :(. I read that it's very tricky to requery a database locally, that's why i'm trying to close the connection and open it again every second... of course it's not working the way I need it to!

Comment: what information do you need me to provide?  I don't even know if there's a way to use javascript to connect to a MS Access database in chrome or firefox (to avoid using activex) :(

Comment: totally ok to connect to Access using JavaScript, just don't understand the context. is it some maintenance program you want to run on your own computer? VBA could be another option or if you just want to monitor, an Excel query...?

Comment: The access database appends the information from a csv file created by a device that monitors voltage.  The idea is to display the V fluctuation per second.  I have created graphic monitors in an html page and just needed to parse the data and "requery" it every second.  But i think i hit a dead end here, I cannot make it work!  Seems simple, but it just doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

what happens if you try it like this?

```
function test() {
  var adOpenForwardOnly = 0,
      adLockReadOnly = 1;

  try {
    var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
    conn.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=C:\\path\\Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
    if (conn.State > 0) {
      var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
      rs.Open("SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 where Time1 = time()", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly);
      value1 = rs.fields("Value1").value;
      document.write(value1);
    } else {
      throw new Error('conn not open...');
    }
    rs.Close();
    conn.Close();
  } catch (someError) {
    alert(someError.message);
  }
}

var i = 0;
while (i === 0) {
  setTimeout(test, 1000);
}
```

Comment: remove the (), just needs the function name

Comment: The only way I can get it to give me new data is to hit refresh :(

Comment: with setInterval(test,1000); only refreshes once and stops

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code:

1. You're using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, so it will execute only once.
2. You're using the parenthesis `()` to send the function as a parameter, but you should only name the function, e.g: `setInterval(test, 1000);`

---

**Another option**

I suggest you to use a recursive `setTimeout` (cause of the database delays). E.g:

```
function test() {
  var adOpenForwardOnly = 0,
    adLockReadOnly = 1;
  var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
  conn.open("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data          Source=C:\\path\\Data.mdb;Persist Security Info=False");
  if (conn) {
    var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    rs.Open("SELECT Table1.* FROM Table1 where Time1 = time()", conn, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly);
    value1 = rs.fields("Value1").value;
    document.write(value1);
  }
  rs.Close();
  conn.Close();

  setTimeout(test, 1000);
}

test();
```

Comment: Thank you! I did what you said but it only did the refresh once and stopped. :( any other suggestion?